# Vue3: How do I access a function inside the methods attribute from a component's setup() method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, components, vuejs3

I have an array containing data of questions that will be displayed. Only one question must be displayed at a time. Once the user selects an answer to a question, they can move to the next one by, either, the click of a button or using the up and down arrow keys.

Here's a gif of the present version:
[image: Screen recording gif]

The `App.vue` file:

```
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
import QuestionCard from "./components/QuestionCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
   components: {
      QuestionCard
   },
   setup() {
      const questionArray = ref([
         {
            id: "123",
            question: "Which of these is a colour in the rainbow?",
            options: [
               'brown', 'red', 'black',
            ],
         }, {
            id: "456",
            question: "How many continents does Earth have?",
            options: [
               1, 7, 6, 9
            ],
         }, {
            id: "789",
            question: "Which of these is a prime number?",
            options: [
               7, 4, 44, 
            ],
         },
      ]);

      let currentQuestion = ref(0);

      return {
         questionArray, currentQuestion
      }
   },
   methods: {
      nextQuestion() {
         if (this.currentQuestion < this.questionArray.length - 1) {
            this.currentQuestion++;
         }
      },
      previousQuestion() {
         if (this.currentQuestion > 0) {
            this.currentQuestion--;
         }
      }
   },
   mounted() {
      console.log('Mounted!!')
      window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
         if (event.code == 'ArrowDown') {
            this.nextQuestion();
         }
         else if (event.code == 'ArrowUp') {
            this.previousQuestion();
         }
      });
   },
   
});
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <div id="top_bar">
         <button @click="previousQuestion">Previous Question (Up key)</button>
         <button @click="nextQuestion">Next Question (Down key)</button>
      </div>

      <div id="question_section">
         <QuestionCard 
            :question="questionArray[currentQuestion].question"
            :answer_options="questionArray[currentQuestion].options"
         ></QuestionCard>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

I have a component called `QuestionCard` that displays the questions and the answer options. Just like in the `App` component, I have added an event listener, in order to detect key presses. Each answer option is given a key code beginning from letter A (ASCII - 65). For example, based on the answer options of the first question in `questionArray` above, the `QuestionCard` for the first question must only respond to just 3 key codes:

- A for brown
- B for red
- C for black

On either

1. pressing one of the keys assigned to an answer option button, or
2. by clicking it,

I want to record the answer options value and pass it to a method called `storeAnswer()`.
I have achieved goal 1 by calling this method and passing the value when a `<button>` is clicked. However, I'm not quite sure how to achieve goal 2.

Here's what I have done - inside the `setup()` method of the `QuestionCard`, I have added listener to the window to detect key releases. On detection, I check if the `key` matches any of the assigned keys to the answer options. If so, I call the `storeAnswer()` method. But, I get an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: storeAnswer is not defined

Here's the code of `QuestionCard.vue`:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
   props: {
      name: String,
      question: String,
      answer_options: Array,
   },
   methods: {
      storeAnswer(ans: any) { 
         this.selectedAns = ans;
         console.log("Button clicked: " + ans);
      }
   },
   setup(props) {
      let selectedAns = ref(null);
      
      // loop through array of answer_options and assign a key code for each one so that it can be detected
      const keyOptions: {keyCode: string, value: any}[] = [];
      for (let i=0; i < props.answer_options.length; i++) {
         keyOptions.push(
            {
               keyCode: String.fromCharCode(65+i),
               value: props.answer_options[i]
            }
         );
      }

      window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
         const keyPressed = event.key.toUpperCase();

         const i = keyOptions.findIndex(Element => Element.keyCode == keyPressed);
         if (i > -1) {            
            selectedAns.value = keyOptions[i].value;
            console.log(`Option you selected is: ${keyPressed + ')' + selectedAns.value}`)
            storeAnswer();
         }
      });

      return {
         selectedAns
      }
   },
});
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <h4>{{ question }}</h4>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li v-for="(option, index) in answer_options" :key="index">
               <button @click="storeAnswer(option)">
                  {{  String.fromCharCode(65 + index) + ') ' + option }}
               </button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- display the selected answer -->
      <p>
         {{ selectedAns }}
      </p>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is XY problem. You shouldn't. Composition api is supposed to replace options api completely, then you won't have problems with their integration. Btw you don't remove event listener, this will result in memory leaks

Comment: Are you saying that I'm using the Composition and Options API together? If so, could you tell me where. I don't quite understand the problem.
@EstusFlask

Comment: setup function is composition api. methods is options api

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create a composable function. Define all your functions and state of the app like this:

```
 // /src/composables/useQuestions.js 
 import {ref, onMounted, computed} from 'vue'

 const questionArray = ref([])
 const currentQuestion = ref(0)
 const selectedAns = ref(null)
 const computed_answer_options = computed(() => {
    const questionObj = questionArray.value[currentQuestion.value]
    if (questionObj) return questionObj.options
    return []
 })
 const computed_question = computed(() => {
    const questionObj = questionArray.value[currentQuestion.value]
    if (questionObj) return questionObj.question
    return null
 })

 export default () => {
    onMounted(() => {
       window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
          if (event.code == 'ArrowDown') {
             nextQuestion();
          }
          else if (event.code == 'ArrowUp') {
             previousQuestion();
          }
       });
    })

    // here you can call function that detect key releases and calls storeAnswer
    // I did't finish logic, but i think you got the point

    return {
       questionArray,
       currentQuestion,
       nextQuestion,
       previousQuestion,
       computed_answer_options,
       computed_question,
       storeAnswer
    }
 }

 const nextQuestion = () => {
    if (currentQuestion.value < questionArray.value.length - 1) {
       currentQuestion.value++;
    }
 }
 const previousQuestion = () => {
    if (currentQuestion.value > 0) {
       currentQuestion.value--;
    }
 }
 const storeAnswer = (ans) => {
    selectedAns.value = ans 
 }
```

in your components use like this:

```
 // App.vue, QuestionCard.vue
 ...,
 setup () {
   const {
       questionArray,
       currentQuestion,
       nextQuestion,
       previousQuestion,
       computed_answer_options,
       computed_question,
       storeAnswer
    } = useQuestions()
   questionArray.value // returns []
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem thanks to [@Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask), who pointed out my misusage of the Vue's Composition API with Options API in my code.

Here's the working code.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import QuestionCard from "./components/QuestionCard.vue";


const questionArray = ref([
   {
      id: "123",
      question: "Which of these is a colour in the rainbow?",
      options: [
         'brown', 'red', 'black',
      ],
      selectedAns: null,
   }, {
      id: "456",
      question: "How many continents does Earth have?",
      options: [
         1, 7, 6, 9
      ],
      selectedAns: 6,
   }, {
      id: "789",
      question: "Which of these is a prime number?",
      options: [
         7, 4, 44, 
      ],
      selectedAns: 4,
   },
]);

const answerOptions = ref([]);
const currentQuestion = ref(0);


// methods to use in the App component -----------------------------------------------------------------
function nextQuestion() {
   if (currentQuestion.value < questionArray.value.length - 1) {
      currentQuestion.value++;
      setAnswerOptions();
   }   
}
function previousQuestion() {
   if (currentQuestion.value > 0) {
      currentQuestion.value--;
      setAnswerOptions();
   }
}
function setAnswerOptions() {
   answerOptions.value.length = 0;

   for (let i=0; i < questionArray.value[currentQuestion.value].options.length; i++) {
      answerOptions.value.push(
         {
            key: String.fromCharCode(65+i),
            value: questionArray.value[currentQuestion.value].options[i]                  
         }
      );
   }
}


// lifecycle hooks--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
onMounted(() => {
   // console.log('App mounted, setting up listeners!!');

   setAnswerOptions();

   window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.code == 'ArrowDown') {
         nextQuestion();
      }
      else if (event.code == 'ArrowUp') {
         previousQuestion();
      }
      
      const i = answerOptions.value.findIndex(element => element.key == event.key.toUpperCase());
      if (i > -1) {
         // console.log(`You have seleced ${answerOptions.value[i].value}, moving to next question`);
         questionArray.value[currentQuestion.value].selectedAns = answerOptions.value[i].value;
         nextQuestion();
      }
   });   

   // console.log('listeners all set!')
});
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <div id='top_bar'>
         <button @click=" previousQuestion ">Previous Question (Up key)</button >
         <button @click=" nextQuestion ">Next Question (Down key)</button >
      </div>

      <div id='question_section'>
         <QuestionCard 
            :id=" questionArray[currentQuestion].id "
            :question=" questionArray[currentQuestion].question "
            :answer_options=" questionArray[currentQuestion].options "
         ></QuestionCard>
         
         <p v-if=" questionArray[currentQuestion].selectedAns != null ">
            {{ 'Your last answer was: ' + questionArray[currentQuestion].selectedAns }}
         </p>
         
         <div id='answer_options_section'>
            <ul>
               <li v-for=" option in answerOptions ">
                  <button :class=" {'selected-option': option.value == questionArray[currentQuestion].selectedAns } " >
                     {{  option.key + ') ' + option.value }}
                  </button>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

QuestionCard.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

// define the props used in this component
const props = defineProps({
   id: String,
   name: String,
   question: String,
   answer_options: Array,
});
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <h5>Question ID: {{ id }}</h5>
      <h4>{{ question }}</h4>
   </div>
</template>
```